# Removing default map label of places in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: labeling, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I've added MapBox map layer in my HTML page using following script.

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken =
    '***********************';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
    zoom: 6,
    center: [84.1015344, 28.3911862]

});
```

Everything is great but there is default map label which is cluttered and I don't want them in my analysis part. So, how can I remove those labels?

Here is the image of the generated map with too much labels in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make change to the default light or dark theme but discovered about Mapbox studio which helps to customize the map according to out need. So, I created Mapbox studio custom map with turning off all the label layers i didn't need for the project.

Comment: Hello, sorry a bit late, can you try to execute the following function inside the javascript console of your browser ? `map.getStyle()`. `map` must be your `mapboxgl.Map` instance.
In the output, look at the `layers` attributes, it's an array containing all the layers loaded in your map. You must find the one displaying the labels and then call :
`map.setLayoutProperty(THE-LAYER-ID-HERE, 'visibility', 'none');` it should fix the problem.